# Diode package designator?

Tags: diodes, markings, bom

I received a job to add distributor part numbers to the existing BOM, which is a bit lacking in detail of description. One of the entries is 1N4148 diode with description: D3515. The other one is diode SS26 with description D5035. I can find some mentions of 3515 being some sort of package size I guess. I can not find any mention of the other one though. Are there any standards that use those codes? Here's how it looks like: [image]

As you can see the numbers are separate from the reference designator, they are under the tab of "Footprint".

Comment: Well, DO-35 is a standard diode package. Some photos of the components in question (with some kind of a reference scale) would be helpful. A 1N4148 diode could come in likely a dozen different packages, and getting it wrong would mean a no-go and returning the parts.

Answer (score 2):

There's **not enough information** given. D3515 (assuming it's not the reference designator) is probably something unique to your company, a pointer to a particular footprint or other database entry.

If I look up 1N4148 on a distributor such as Digikey (which will find 1N4148xxxxx part numbers), I will find about a dozen different packages that are available from die to DO-213AA (the oh-so familiar through-hole glass package) to 0402 (0.04" x 0.02" surface mount), die etc. I might guess that it's the glass through-hole package but in 2019 it is probably more likely it's an SMT version of some kind.

If the information does not exist in the EDA software, you can look up previous purchase orders for that part, physically go look at what is marked on the packaging, as someone who knows, etc. However, the information may (**should**) exist in the PCB design software.

That will give you one manufacturer and one part number, which may help you find the distributor part number (though the *distributor* part number can vary with things like whether it's a reel or cut tape or bulk for the same product). If you look up what was ordered last time it should give you a hint. The PCB design software may list alternative manufacturers, not just one.

So ideally, EDA software and/or physical evidence-> Manufacturer name(s) + Manufacturer part number(s) -> Distributor website (to look up their part number)

Chances are you'll have to interact with the designer(s) and purchasing folks during this process, otherwise you're probably not doing it right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately the  job is done through a freelancing platform with all the specific troubles that come with it. I'm trying to get more info from the client but he's been silent as of now. I want to get my hands on the actual design files, that'll make the life easier. I just thought that maybe there IS some standard that I'm unaware of that specifies the footprint exactly with these numbers, but alas, it seems that the numbers are useless for this purpose.

Comment: Yikes, doesn't sound like the ideal situation.